# Multiple pages application going to be slower

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have two UI Class in separate .py files, and I'm going to switch pages using a controller py file and works properly.
Here is my first UI that I called main.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
position = 3


class Ui_MainWindow(QObject):
    settingSignal = pyqtSignal()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
        self.frame.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.optical = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.upgrade = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.menu = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.calibration = QLabel(self.frame)
        self.media = QLabel(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.imageChange(position)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def imageChange(self, Pos):
        self.menu.setGeometry(QRect(160, 410, 200, 200))
        self.upgrade.setGeometry(QRect(510, 410, 200, 200))
        self.optical.setGeometry(QRect(860, 410, 200, 200))
        self.calibration.setGeometry(QRect(1210, 410, 200, 200))
        self.media.setGeometry(QRect(1520, 410, 200, 200))
        self.optical.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.calibration.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.menu.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.media.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.upgrade.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")

        if Pos == 1:
            self.menu.setGeometry(QRect(110, 360, 300, 300))
            self.menu.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);")
        elif Pos == 2:
            self.upgrade.setGeometry(QRect(460, 360, 300, 300))
            self.upgrade.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);")
        elif Pos == 3:
            self.optical.setGeometry(QRect(810, 360, 300, 300))
            self.optical.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);")
        elif Pos == 4:
            self.calibration.setGeometry(QRect(1160, 360, 300, 300))
            self.calibration.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);")
        elif Pos == 5:
            self.media.setGeometry(QRect(1470, 360, 300, 300))
            self.media.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);")

    def Control(self, key):
        global position
        if key == "LEFT":
            if position > 1:
                position -= 1
            else:
                position = 1
            self.imageChange(position)
        elif key == "RIGHT":
            if position < 5:
                position += 1
            else:
                position = 5
            self.imageChange(position)
        elif key == "OK":
            if position == 1:
                self.settingSignal.emit()
```

And second UI file I called setting.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_SettingWindow(QObject):
    mainSignal = pyqtSignal()

    def setupUi(self, SettingWindow):
        if not SettingWindow.objectName():
            SettingWindow.setObjectName(u"MenuWindow")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(SettingWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
        self.frame.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        SettingWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SettingWindow)

    def Control(self, key):
        global position
        if key == "BACK":
            self.mainSignal.emit()
```

I'm going to switch between UIs using Controller.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from ui import main, setting

PageIsNow = "main"
RemoteKey = ""


class InitWindow(QMainWindow):
    keyPressed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QEvent)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InitWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Ui_Main = main.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.uiSetting = setting.Ui_SettingWindow()
        self.startUIWindow()
        self.keyPressed.connect(self.on_key)

    def startSetting(self):
        global PageIsNow
        self.uiSetting.setupUi(self)
        PageIsNow = "setting"
        self.uiSetting.mainSignal.connect(self.startUIWindow)
        self.show()

    def startUIWindow(self):
        global PageIsNow
        self.Ui_Main.setupUi(self)
        PageIsNow = "main"
        self.Ui_Main.settingSignal.connect(self.startSetting)
        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super(InitWindow, self).keyPressEvent(event)
        self.keyPressed.emit(event)

    def on_key(self, event):
        global PageIsNow, RemoteKey
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
            RemoteKey = "LEFT"
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
            RemoteKey = "RIGHT"
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            RemoteKey = "UP"
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
            RemoteKey = "DOWN"
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            RemoteKey = "OK"
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace:
            RemoteKey = "BACK"
        else:
            RemoteKey = ""
        self.OpenPage()

    def OpenPage(self):
        global PageIsNow, RemoteKey
        if PageIsNow == "setting":
            self.uiSetting.Control(RemoteKey)
        elif PageIsNow == "main":
            self.Ui_Main.Control(RemoteKey)
        else:
            RemoteKey = ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = InitWindow()
    w.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Code is simple and runnable without error, and the strategy is simple, keyboard listener is in controller when key is pressed, opens Control method in main.py or setting.py and pyqtSignal triggers are for opening another UI using controller. My problem is: When I switch between UIs multiple times, program speed significantly going to be slow. Is there any ideas to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the ui getting slower is that you're connecting the `self.uiSetting.mainSignal` and `self.Ui_Main.settingSignal` everytime you run the respective functions, which causes a "partial recursion".
The results is that the functions related to those windows are called for **every time** the signal has been connected, including the connection itself:

1. `startUIWindow` is called, which connects `Ui_Main.settingSignal`
2. when `settingSignal` is emitted, it calls `startSetting` which does the opposite
3. when `mainSignal` is emitted, it calls `startUIWindow` which also connects *again* the signal
4. when `settingSignal` is emitted again, it will call `startSettings` **twice**, which will cause the `mainSignal` to be again connected **twice**
5. when `mainSignal` is emitted, it will call `startUIWindow` **three** times, which will connect again the `settingsSignal` three other times, etc...

As you can see, this is obviously *not* a good approach.

The only thing I can suggest you for this *specific* case, is to add a simple bool variable to remember if the connection has already been made:

```
class InitWindow(QMainWindow):
    keyPressed = pyqtSignal(QEvent)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InitWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mainConnected = self.settingsConnected = False
        self.Ui_Main = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.uiSetting = Ui_SettingWindow()
        self.startUIWindow()
        self.keyPressed.connect(self.on_key)

    def startSetting(self):
        # ...
        if not self.settingsConnected:
            self.settingsConnected = True
            self.uiSetting.mainSignal.connect(self.startUIWindow)

    def startUIWindow(self):
        # ...
        if not self.mainConnected:
            self.mainConnected = True
            self.Ui_Main.settingSignal.connect(self.startSetting)
```

But I have to be blunt: this is just the *major* issue with your code, as in reality there are lots of other problems, including:

- globals should be avoided like hell;
- strings should not be used for variable comparison;
- creating a signal for key events that just calls a function that accepts the event (and it's also the *next* function) is completely useless; you either integrate the other function within the `keyPressEvent`, or you just call it from there;
- there's no benefit in continuously calling `setupUi` everytime the window is swiched
- trying to mimic the output of `pyuic` is not a good idea; I see that you tried to circumvent some of the issues coming from that approach by inheriting from QObject, but it doesn't have any sense nor benefit; to correctly use those files follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), or just build your interfaces with QWidget (or QMainWindow, in your case) subclasses; also, many of the calls you "inherited" from pyuic are completely useless for your case (most importantly: `setObjectName()`, `QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName`);
- do *not* use globals unless you **really** know exactly how to use them and when you really need them, and if you know how to use them and when you really need them, you will probably *not* use them at all;